# iOS Instruments : Timer's time is not matching with the sum of running times in call tree

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, instruments, xamarin.forms

I am analysing an app's slow performance using iOS Instruments. To load a login page it takes around 25 seconds. In Instruments, the timer shows 25 seconds to load the page. But when I sum the running times of the call tree, It is just around 4 seconds only. I want to know where the slowness is occuring. Is there anyway to force instruments to show all the time taken in call tree?

Note: I tried Xamarin profiler also. It shows maximum time taken by any call as 1E-06 ms. Is there any way to know the time taken by the whole method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the Stopwatch class? It is supported in Project Core Libraries and can be used in a high-resolution mode for higher accuracy. It would allow you to time the execution of a particular method (which sounds like what you are attempting to accomplish). You can find Microsoft documentation and examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will consider using stopwatch as a last option since we need to provide the performance insights through xamarin profiler or instruments to the third party SDK developers.